# UIButton event is not firing, even if I connect it through xib

Tags: xcode, uikit

I am creating a calculator game, in which I have to popup a `UIAlertView`, I customized the `UIAlertView` and put a `UITableView` programatically into it, When the user tap any of its cell I show a `UIView` on the top of `UITableView`, this view has a button, when I clicked that button the event does not fires, I have also installed it manually, but it doesn't work, previously the attachment of event with button is generating an error, for that I uninstalled the event in dealloc, and fix the problem, but after it still the event is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

i was have case such your and i have to add it pragmatically
in .h declare

```
UIButton *btn;
```

in .m add it to the UIView

```
    UIView *TempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    if (btn) {
        [btn removeFromSuperview];
//        [btn release]; // for not using arc
    }
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 25, 25)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickMe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [TempView addSubview:btn];

    [self.view addSubview:TempView];
```

and the action is

```
-(void)ClickMe:(id)sender{
        //here is an action
}
```

it's working for me

Comment: I have added you code Mina but generating an error, and still not working, and not even showing the button on the UIView, Please review my Question, and try to understand the problem, I have done all the stuff you have provided, Please Help, thanks